# Аплоэд файла с использованием multer и обрыв соединения - как очистит память?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Использую для аплоада файла библиотеку multer. Предполагается заливать на сервер большие файлы - порядка 3Гб. В точке входа все оборачиваю в domain. В домене обрабатываю ошибки - вывожу их в консоль.

Тестирую обрыв соединения - закрываю браузер во время загрузки файла. В консоли при этом ничего не выводится. На жестком диске вижу загруженный файл (естественно недокачанный и с неполным размером). Удаляю его руками - он через секунду появляется снова. Рестарчу сервер - размер файла становится чуть-чуть больше и теперь его можно удалить.

Пробую обрабатывать разрыв соединения:

```
req.on('close', () => {
  console.log('close!');
  fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('err:');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`connection was failed. unfinished uploading file cleaned`);
  });
});
```

В консоли вижу сначала 'close!' а потом ошибку домена (но это не err - пробовал ее кастомизировать чтобы отличить - это не она). Т.е. удалить файл средствами node.js не получается.

Как можно очистить память от этого недокачанного файла?

Comment: Что у вас находится в переменной `path`? Откуда вы её взяли?

Comment: @vihtor ну на самом деле там написано path.join(process.cwd(), `static/files/fws/${ req.body.fwId }/main/${ req.files[0].originalname.replace(' ', '_') - сократил для читаемости

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что делает `domain` мидлвара и каким образом вы назначаете событие `close` к запросу. Дело в втом, что `multer` не передаст обработку запроса в вашу функцию, до тех пор, пока файл не будет полностью загружен. Следовательно, код `req.on('close',...` , при обрые загрузки, выполниться не должен. Поясните, пожалуйста, каким образом получается так, что вы всё таки слушаете это событие? Ваша функция добавлена в обработку запроса до `multer` мидлвары? **А лучше приведите весь код**.

Comment: @vihtor да, я назначаю обработчик on.close до передачи управления мультеру

Comment: @vihtor на счет показать код - вы сами попросили) вот: https://github.com/muturgan/multer-question/blob/master/fws-upload-routes.ts

Comment: @vihtor а это чтобы было понятней что такое "В точке входа все оборачиваю в domain": https://github.com/muturgan/multer-question/blob/master/server.ts

Comment: Вопрос актуален ещё?

Comment: @vihtor еще да... пришлось преключиться на другие горящие задачи а на это подзабили пока(

Comment: интересная задача, гляну сегодня-завтра

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В топку multer!

Короче, юзайте busboy. Он из всех библиотек самый низкоуровневый. Текстовые поля парсит, а на каждый файл в реквесте создает readableStream, который можно обработать как хочешь.

Я например создал таймер, и если не получаю в течении некоторого времени новый чанк данных, то закрываю соединение и дестрою поток.

Все работает чудесно.